# Is it possible to display ASCII characters in Javascript's pop up confirm() or alert()?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to display characters like `<`, `>`, `'`, etc in Javascript's pop up `alert()` or `confirm()`?

`<` is automatically changed to `&lt;`

etc.

The same still occurs if I change the symbols to their unicode like `<` to `\u003c` etc.

Comment: Can you show us your code - i think its probably the way you are setting up the string to display on the alert / confirm

Comment: Turns out that the string is converted by `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute()`, not by javascript. I've created another thread for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046717/httpservletrequest-setattribute-converts-ascii-chars

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you: `\<` or

```
\\>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its a browser problem / your code (ie how you are setting the string to be displayed) because it works fine for me - what browser are you using ?

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/uyMhJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use alert("<") to display <. If not:

1. the alert function has been over written, you could use alert(alert) to display the define.
2. there is a bug in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `alert();` to external .js file. It should work fine.

Comment: Why would that make a difference ?