# HttpServletRequest.setAttribute() converts ASCII chars

Tags: java, servlets

When I call `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute(name, string)` the ASCII content like `<` of attribute string is converted to `&lt;`, etc.

What is the workaround so that the content is not converted? I want to display the content in a javascript `confirm()`.

Update:
String is output using `<c:out>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setAttribute does not escape content, it just places an object into the Map. Most probably your templating engine does that.

Comment: I use struts1+tiles. Do you think they do that? Thanks.

Comment: Most probably yes. How do you printout the variable?

Comment: `<c:out/>` escapes content by default. You need to use `escapeXml="false"`. Your IDE should provide auto-complete for that, otherwise have a look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such conversion see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) or http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 1):

`<c:out>` has a attribute to enable XML escaping. And interesting by default it is true. Below is an example to disable XML escaping.

```
    <c:out value="${user.company}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that's interesting. And strange.

Comment: It's the proper thing to do. Otherwise 95% of all JSP based applications out there would be XSS vulnerable.